# Database Table Partitioning

Tags: sql-server-ce

Our application has the potential to generate huge database files (1 GB and larger) depending on how it is used.

We are currently using (and will continue to use) SQL Server CE as our DBMS platform and as such we are limited to a 4 GB database size.  There are also performance issues that manifest when the database size approaches the 4 GB limit.

So in order to enable future scalability and essentially solve the performance problems associated with huge databases, we are planning to partition the single database file into multiple database files - 1 for each day of the year.

Our current POR is to implement this partitioning in C++ code (in terms of naming the database files uniquely for each day and modifying the queries to account for multiple databases).

Is there a smarter way to implement this where we could perhaps leverage some functionality of SQL Server CE that is unbeknownst to us?

And yes, we are stuck with SQL Server CE for the immediate future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no smarter way or hidden feature to help you